# Custom error response without htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, errordocument

I know how to create a custom error page using the apache htaccess file:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /error.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
```

But is it possible to have a custom error page without using the htaccess file?
I have access to the server and all its settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same code inside your apache virtualhost ; it will have the same behaviour.

Comment: do you mean the httpd.conf? if so where do I find it? also I only have one website running from this server

Comment: The virtualhosts are usually in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` directory.

Then in your virtualhost file, you will have to add your code inside the `<Directory "/your/wwww/directory">` tag.

Comment: It didn't work for me sadly... I'm just using xampp